# clj-time - how to get local-date from curent time in a different timezone

Tags: clojure, timezone, clj-time

I'm sitting in the America/Sao_Paulo (or some other random timezone) and now I want to get a LocalDate for the current date in Europe/London.

How can I achieve this?

(I've got a localDate that I know is in london, and I want to check if it's before the current date using clj-time.core/after?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know [Clojure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure). So I'll use Java syntax which you can translate.

> I'm sitting in the America/Sao_Paulo (or some other random timezone)

Irrelevant. Whether your tushy is in Tokyo, Reykjavík, or São Paulo, that has nothing to do with asking for the current date in `Europe/London` time zone.

> and now I want to get a LocalDate for the current date in Europe/London.

Call [`LocalDate.now`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#now(java.time.ZoneId)) while passing the time zone of interest.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ;
LocalDate currentDateInLondon = LocalDate.now( zoneId ) ;
```

> I've got a localDate that I know is in london, and I want to check if it's before the current date

You can compare [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) objects by calling `isEqual`, `isBefore`, and `isAfter`.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
boolean isCurrentDateInLondonBeforeThatDate = currentDateInLondon.isBefore( localDate ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

### NOTE:

**The `clj-time` library is based on the old Joda Time library.  Both of these have been deprecated in favor of `java.time` (available since JDK 8).  It is best to use Java interop with java.time instead of the older `clj-time` library.**

The package `java.time` is basically Joda Time 2.0, but rewritten to be cleaner and to correct some corner cases.  Both were created by the same person.

---

### Answer:

In Java, a `LocalDate` doesn't have a timezone. That is the whole point.

It is used for things like a birthday, such as 1999-12-31, where we don't consider your birthday to have a timezone.

For the same reason, the `LocalDate` doesn't have any time associated with it, just as your birthday is considered to be the entire day.

See the `java.time` docs for more information:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html

---

From the JavaDocs:

> **Dates and Times**
>
> Instant is essentially a numeric timestamp. The
> current Instant can be retrieved from a Clock. This is useful for
> logging and persistence of a point in time and has in the past been
> associated with storing the result from System.currentTimeMillis().
>
> LocalDate stores a date without a time. This stores a date like
> '2010-12-03' and could be used to store a birthday.
>
> LocalTime stores a time without a date. This stores a time like
> '11:30' and could be used to store an opening or closing time.
>
> LocalDateTime stores a date and time. This stores a date-time like
> '2010-12-03T11:30'.
>
> ZonedDateTime stores a date and time with a time-zone. This is useful
> if you want to perform accurate calculations of dates and times taking
> into account the ZoneId, such as 'Europe/Paris'. Where possible, it is
> recommended to use a simpler class without a time-zone. The widespread
> use of time-zones tends to add considerable complexity to an
> application.

---

**Helper functions:**

I have added [some convenience functions](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/20.12.03b/api/tupelo.java-time) to aid the usage of `java.time` that you may find useful.

Comment: Depending on your currrent time and zone, other zones are a day ahead or behind. So i think OP s asking "is it already tomorrow in london"

Comment: That question still cannot be answered unless you have a `LocalDateTime` and a TimeZone. Then you can convert each to an `Instant` and compare those.

Comment: Yes @cfrick has it right. The current date is different in different parts of the world, but I need the current date in London, regardless of what timezone is set on the server.

Comment: In that case, Basil showed the answer you need:  `LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ))`.  It is usually best to use Java interop with `java.time`. Note also that the older clj-time library is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

There seems not to be a function to get the `LocalDate` from
a `DateTime` or alike in `clj-time` -- but *Joda Time* has
`.toLocalDate`.  So e.g. you can do something like this:

```
(defn date-at-zone
  [instant zone-id]    
  (.toLocalDate                                                                                                                                                         
   (t/to-time-zone                             
    instant                                                                   
    (t/time-zone-for-id zone-id))))                                        
                                                                  
 (let [instant (t/date-time 2020 12 12 1)                                  
       london-date (date-at-zone instant "Europe/London")
       sao-paulo-date (date-at-zone instant "America/Sao_Paulo")]
   (print (map str [instant london-date sao-paulo-date (t/after? london-date sao-paulo-date)])))       
; → (2020-12-12T01:00:00.000Z 2020-12-12 2020-12-11 true)
```

(e.g. on 2020-12-12T01:00 Zulu it is still 2020-12-11 in Sao Paulo and
therefor London "is strictly after" Sao Paulo when looking at just the
date -- or it's already "tomorrow" in London)